# Primefaces keyboard component, custom layout

Tags: primefaces, keyboard

I need to create a custom keyboard in primefaces, for this I used the p: keyboard component, with the option of custom layoutTemplate, between the keys I need to add is the minus (-) symbol, but I can not get it to show on the keyboard , this symbol is always omitted.

Please anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Comma and minus character both are considered as separator. Use hex code of separator to show as a symbol.

```
<p:keyboard id="vectorFile" value="#{tracingSearch.vectorFileFilter}" layout="custom" layoutTemplate="123,456,789,&#x2212;" />
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the character "&#x2212;" Is this "−", and the character I need is this "-" whose value in hex is "2d", this is important because it is used as part of an access password. And when I replace with 2d it does not work.